# Passing cell value into string C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As above. The string id is a NULL value although the .Value is not NULL when I am debugging.

```
string id = dataGridView1[columnindex, rowindex].Value.ToString();
```

Tried to pass the value into id by changing `.Value` into `.FormattedValue`, but does not work too.

Comment: any exception for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string id = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

then try

```
string id = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].EditedValueString();
```